# split a line with special character

Tags: perl

Tried to split some numbers like the following:

```
$line = "6 13  2";

@a = split(/\s+/, $line)
```

But it didn't work.  Turned out the space is not simple white space, vim editor told me the white space actually has two bytes \20\02.

I tried to preprocess the line by the following, but it didn't seem to work.

```
$line =~ s/\x02//g;
```

Any idea how to split it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `$line =~ s/\x02//g` worked for me. Are there more funky characters you didn't account for?

Comment: That's a Unicode U+2002 (EN SPACE), judging from the UTF-8 that I was able to copy from my browser and analyze.  You would need to use a named character class to split on that, I think (and be working with Unicode 'enabled').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to inspect your data:

```
use Data::Dump;

$line = "6 13  2";

dd $line;
```

Outputs:

```
pack("H*","36e280823133e28082e2808232")
```

Or perhaps more helpful:

```
use Data::Dump;

$line = "6 13  2";

dd split //, $line;
```

Outputs:

```
(
  6,
  "\xE2",
  "\x80",
  "\x82",
  1,
  3,
  "\xE2",
  "\x80",
  "\x82",
  "\xE2",
  "\x80",
  "\x82",
  2,
)
```

Looks like you've got some encoding issues to deal with.

Changing to [`utf8`](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Data::Dump;

my $line = "6 13  2";

dd split /\s+/, $line;
```

Outputs:

```
(6, 13, 2)
```

Comment: Note, that only effects the encoding of the source code.  If you're bringing in data from an external source, you'll still need to deal with that encoding too.

Comment: @codingFun, `use utf8;` tells Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: Miller & ikegami thanks for the points! How do I handle text from external source then? That's the problem I ran into now.

Comment: @codingFun Read [`perlopentut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) for starters.

Comment: @Miller  thanks a lot for the link, it really helped. I used `binmode(STDIN, ":encoding(UTF-8)");` and it took care of the problem for me!